# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET angular api request causes duplicates?

Tags: .net, angular, iis

I have an application with a .NET c# middle tier and angular front end.  I am calling an api which results in a long running process.  In IE I captured a message saying net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.  In Chrome, I'm seeing a failed status after 10 minutes.

I looked in our log tables and event viewer.  The process is running on the server without failure, but something is causing the api controller method to run multiple times, every 5 minutes.  In my developer tools there is no network indicator that a second call is being made.

Is there a timeout setting in IIS or web.config that might cause this?

Comment: In my case the api was sending a class as response and that class was inherit with some class and a property of that class was not initializing thats why causing this error, simply by fixing or removing.

Comment: Same thing is happening with my code, is there any way to stop the retry call?

Answer (score 2):

**Possibilities**

1. The Server response passing from the backend is maybe not in the correct format.
2. If the response time (For that particular API) is greater than 10 sec, then you need to enable the IIS timeout to a greater value.
   In angular HTTP service design pattern if server does not respond back then it will automatically retrigger the API call from front end itself

Comment: Would crossing the IIS Timeout threshold cause the server to retry the process in it's entirety?  Would it not just simply error?