# Httpclient angular post request if failed then, inserting multiple entries in database

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

While making request from angular, an error occurring to endpoint "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET", and then, may be it is retrying again and inserting duplicate records in db.

In angular I am sending post request like this.

```
public post(url: string, request: any): any {
    return this.httpClient.post(environment.emp_api_endpoint + url, request, this.options);
}
```

I have verified the same call from postman, it was working fine and inserting records only one time.

I have tried below code but it's also not working.

```
public postWithNoRetry(url: string, request: any): any {
    return this.httpClient.post(environment.emp_api_endpoint + url, request, this.options)
    .pipe(
        retry(0)
      );
}
```

Please suggest me, How can I stop my call not to do retry after failed/timeout/reset.

I have added comment on this [net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET angular api request causes duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48932750/6310485) question looking similar to my problem. But not got any satisfactory answer.

**Updated**

```
uploadCustomSignByExcel(data: any): Observable<ServiceResponse<boolean>> {
    return this.apiService.post(String.Format(SignsConstants.API.CustomUploadExcelSign, this._offer.Id), data);
}

  uploadCustomSigns() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(this.file.name, this.file, this.file.name);
    const requestId = this.NewGuid();
    formData.append('RequestId', requestId);
    formData.append('CsdCodes', requestId);
    this.uploadCustomSignByExcel(formData).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.IsSuccess) {
        // this.eventService.getExcelUploadStatus(requestId, this.uploadProductsCallBack);
      } else {
        console.log(data.ErrorMessages[0]);
      }
      this.file = null;
      this.filename = 'Browse...';
    },
    _ => {
      this.file = null;
      this.filename = 'Browse...';
    });
  }
```

And then Calling uploadCustomSigns from button click.

**UPDATE 2**

[API sending ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in 2.1 mins, but client is making autoretry in 61 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64088006/6310485)

Comment: I don't think `HttpClient` is ever retrying without explicitly setting it to

Comment: httpClient not retry by default. Please add the code when you call post...

Comment: Hi @DerekMenénedez, I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: The mentioned code doesn't have any retry mechanism. Remove that pipe() as well. I think your project has a HTTP Error Interceptor(https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) which is retrying failed requests. Try searching **HttpErrorResponse** in your project.

Comment: Hi @SujitKumarSingh, I had also tried after removing the reference of interceptor from module. And I had also tried by making an fresh new angular application without any interceptor.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible version of this issue using https://codesandbox.io/s/angular? No need to expose actual API.

Comment: Can you please verify here, https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mccarthy-7g062

Comment: @HPSingh I see no issue with the shared code(https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mccarthy-7g062). I was suspecting this before that the issue is from the serer side due to the error **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. Can you also check whether while uploading the file, the server encounters an error and re-starts itself?

Comment: You can also look at the browser's Network tab to see if a duplicate call has actually been triggered.

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh, I have seen browser network tab showing no duplicate, but a third party utility "http analyzer" showing another request after around 60sec. -- if it encounters from server side, I have checked it with postman(and with postman data is inserting only once).