# API sending ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in 2.1 mins, but client is making autoretry in 61 seconds

Tags: angular, google-chrome, iis

I am facing problem with duplicate records inserting in database.I am struggling from 2-3 days but not got any solution.

I have posted a question ([Httpclient angular post request if failed then, inserting multiple entries in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64064792/6310485)) before,as I was thinking it is Angular HttpClient fault. But after reading so many blogs and questions figured out it is mentioned in http1.1 protocol to retry.

But I have not found any way to handle this without changing my Api code(How can I encourage my API team to change for double request).

The problem I have seen there, I am getting 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' in 2.1 mins but retry call initiates in 1 min(retry call was not shown in network tab, I have used HTTP Analyzer).

Can it be handled on from client side(angular). Or if not then why it is going after 1 min(On client side it is not mentioned anywhere).

Or what min setting can I do on server so that time exceeds for retry after 2.1 min(as of my server request timeout).

Server I am using for API: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

Comment: Due to the problems of different browsers,Chrome will resend the request after the connection fails or there is a problem.I suggest you access the api with another browser to see if the same problem occurs. If it can be accessed normally or there is only one request, then the problem is on Chrome.

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang, I have tried with Microsoft Edge and Mozilla, same is happing there also(Sending duplicate/retry request).

Comment: Do you use any vpn while access the site?Or is there any setting or firewall kill the request which make the server return connection reset?

Comment: No, I don't use VPN for access site, for firewall setting I don't know. But in 1 min there is auto/silent retry request goes to server, which is making duplicate data in DB. Is there any firewall setting for it?

Comment: I don't think it is problem about iis. You can get support here:https://support.microsoft.com/

Comment: @BruceZhang, I have read it <https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4> , from it we ca say on closing the connection httpclient(following http1.1 spec) may retry. So That's why I have said, may there be some misconfiguration done by API team on IIS. Can anyone tell me what it can be. So that I can insist/encourage to API team to change that.